# groovy.lang.MissingMethodException when running my test

Tags: groovy, geb

When I attempt to run a .groovy test, the console is kicking back this error:

> Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: GebConfig.waiting() is applicable for argument types: (GebConfig$_run_closure1) values: [GebConfig$_run_closure1@659499f1]
>   Possible solutions: wait(), wait(long), toString(), toString(), wait(long, int), main([Ljava.lang.String;)
>   groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: GebConfig.waiting() is applicable for argument types: (GebConfig$_run_closure1) values: [GebConfig$_run_closure1@659499f1]
>   Possible solutions: wait(), wait(long), toString(), toString(), wait(long, int), main([Ljava.lang.String;)
>       at GebConfig.run(GebConfig.groovy:28)
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

My GebConfig.groovy is set up as follows:

```
    import geb.driver.BrowserStackDriverFactory
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver


    baseUrl = "https://ourtestingurl.com/"

    /*driver = 'chrome'
     environments {
     'chrome' {
     def chromeDriver = new File('src/test/resources/chromedriver.exe')
     System.setProperty('webdriver.chrome.driver', chromeDriver.absolutePath)
     driver = { new ChromeDriver() }
     driver.manage().window().maximize()
     }
     'firefox' {
     def FirefoxDriver = new File('src/test/resources/geckodriver.exe')
     System.setProperty('webdriver.gecko.driver', geckoDriver.absolutePath)
     driver = { new FirefoxDriver() }
     }
     }
     */
    reportsDir = new File("target/geb-reports1")

    waiting {
        timeout = 50
        retryInterval = 0.5
        slow { timeout = 52 }
        reallyslow { timeout = 80}
    }

    String USERNAME = "username";
    String AUTOMATE_KEY = "niceTry";
    String URL = "https://" + USERNAME + ":" + AUTOMATE_KEY + "@hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub";
    driver = {
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setCapability("os", "Windows");
        caps.setCapability("os_version", "10");
        caps.setCapability("browser", "Chrome");
        caps.setCapability("browser_version", "75.0");
        caps.setCapability("browserstack.local", "false");
        caps.setCapability("browserstack.debug", "true");
        caps.setCapability("browserstack.selenium_version", "3.14.0");
        WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(URL), caps);
    }
```

I'm at a complete loss and have spent my entire day trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently when opening an existing project into intellij where it mixed groovy and java. Intellij only recognized the java source folders, so I had to modify the project to use the src/main/groovy folder. Have you looked at project setup for whatever ide you're using?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had a chance to check that this is the cause but the proper waiting block syntax can be found here -> https://gebish.org/manual/current/#waiting-presets

So your waiting block should look something like this ->

```
waiting {
   timeout = 50
   retryInterval = 0.5
   presets {
     slow { timeout = 52 }
     reallyslow { timeout = 80}
   }
 }
```